# Associated entities on lifecycle of modified within ORM with JPA annotation

Tags: java, jpa, orm, spring-data

With in my domain module i have multiple kind of associations between entities as usual, however I would like to have some operations on associated entities with in one entity once the [state](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/253U81) of this entity changed with in ORM.

A common practice is too use annotation like `@Preupdate` or `@Prepersist`  etc, but how can i access the associated entities and manage(all kind of operations) their state with in ORM as well.

An example to demonstrate the question.

```
public class EntityOne {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "generator")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "attribute_to_join")
    private EntityTwo entity;


    ....

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    void proxyOperation() {
    ...
    }
}
```

How can i manage the state of affected entities, i.e `EntityTwo` with in `proxyOperation` method ? which indeed, is going to trigger when ever an instance of EntityOne is persisted or updated.